# c# compare array of string and array of type

Tags: c#

I have two arrays.

Structure for first `array1`:

```
["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

Structure for second `array2`:

> It is a `List of Type`

```
Type
    [0]
       firstName: "A"
       lastName: "Sam"
    [1]
       firstName: "B"
       lastName: "Mark"
    [2]
       firstName: "X"
       lastName: "Steve"
    [3]
       firstName: "E"
       lastName: "Mike"
```

I want to compare both the arrays and return `lastName` when `array1` and `array2` match with `firstName`. So the output will be something like this.

```
["Sam", "Mark", "Mike"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ to get the values you need

```
List<string> result = array2.Where(x => array1.Contains(x.firstName))
                            .Select(x => x.lastName).ToList();
```

What this does is.. filters the array2 to only the Type's firstName that match up with `array1` and then selects the last names from that matched list.